# Validation going wrong with @ character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using javascript for password validation:

```
$.validator.addMethod('mypassword', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (value.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/));
},
'Password must contain at least one numeric and one uppercase alphabetic character.');
```

I need the password to be at least one numeric and one uppercase alphabetic character. But, if i enter the characters such as `@, # ,$` with one numeric and one uppercase alphaberic character in password, it still shows the error message.

```
Password9 accepted
Password@1 not accepted
```

Answer (score 1):

This part in your regex does not allow `@`:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]
```

If you don't want any limit, then change `[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}` to `.{8,}`.

Answer (score 1):

According to your regular expression, your password must consist of at least 8 alphanumeric characters and nothing else. Your second password does not match this criterion. Try

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/
```

Yet I am not sure this is what you want, as you may want to restrict the set of permitted characters in order to avoid, e.g. non-english letters like äöü.

You might want to list all permitted characters, like so

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z\%\&\/\$\@\#]{8,}$/
```

Or try to specify a unicode range:

[Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes)

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function(){  
       var regex=/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])[!-~]{8,}$/;    
    var arr=["Password9","Password@1","password@1"];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     console.info(arr[i]+"\t"+(regex.test(arr[i])?"accepted":"not accepted"));
    }   
    })();
```

try it